# Why do my Excel IF statements generate an error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel 2016

I can't use IF statements when using Excel. If I try, no matter how simple the statement, I get "There is something wrong with this formula". I can set values from other cells, I can do SUM etc but not an IF.

These work

```
=1+2 (shows FALSE)
=SUM(A1:A6)
```

This doesn't work

```
=IF(1+2,3,4) (get error)
```

I don't have this problem at all when using Excel 2007 (yes it's old) and it shows the value of 4 in the cell no problem. I tried four different data types in the cell (general, number, text and custom) with no luck. I performed a quick repair and an online repair which seemed to download the entire office application and reinstall it also with no luck. If anyone has a clue I'd be most grateful. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: maybe you local setting use `;` instead of `,` for the delimiter.

Comment: Does if(true, 1, 2) work?

Comment: TomStroemer thank you sir but it doesn't work... because Scott Craner hit the nail on the head. This is the second time in a few weeks he's fixed me up. He actually tried to tell me about my local settings last time but it didn't sink in. I use | as my delimiter in my local settings so it's the delimiter when I export to CSV so I don't have to deal with commas in the content. I didn't realize it would affect formulas as well. Anyway that fixed it.Scott do you want to put up a real answer so I can mark it?

Comment: No, seems like a typo more than a problem.

Comment: Your call. Definitely a problem for me as I didn't realize that the local setting delimiter affected formulas in Excel. Anyway thank you again for getting me up and running.

Comment: I think an answer would be useful for others.  I didn't know local settings affected formulae and maybe other don't either?  It doesn't affect VBA UDF, does it?  Maybe we need to edit the title of the question so that people can find the answer when they are having this problem?